# Replacing Me.BeginInvoke() when refactoring to a module

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, delegates

I am trying to refactor some code from a main form, where it worked perfectly, to a module, where it does not work.

In the working version, all information coming in through the serial port is properly handled. Threads/delegates are created here, which finish when they successfully translate the information according to the giant PLM() function below:

https://github.com/ocdtrekkie/HAController/blob/a8def5916686207b0ac4a0707c9406ad6ba39cfa/Form1.vb#L197

When I moved all of this to the module, most of the code works great. I managed to get the SerialPort object created and handled properly in the module. I can send connections to the serial port just fine and everything, however, Me.BeginInvoke() can't be used in a module. I discovered that putting handler() there instead works to create a single thread, and it'll handle a single command, but the usual threading is no longer occurring. So handler() was not the right choice of what I should put here.

https://github.com/ocdtrekkie/HAController/blob/9504237b2a220f1eaf946bff0c86906a2ad5fb43/modInsteon.vb#L181

I know almost nothing about how threading works, to be completely honest, and I know that the code not working right revolves mostly around this one line, I just don't have the foggiest clue what it needs to be.

**Edit: Let's see if I can provide better information.**
(It's amazing I can rack up a downvote before any responder understands what I need or don't need!)

I do not want to make significant changes to the structure of these methods if I can help it, because I am still trying to make some sense of them, and keep them fairly parallel with the original source.

The original author's explanation of what it does may be more useful than my own understanding: http://www.madreporite.com/insteon/receiving.html

> In Visual Basic 2005 (this also applies to 2008), the SerialPort object is assigned its own thread and runs in parallel with the rest of your application. In principle this means it can keep up with the serial device regardless of what the main program gets bogged down with. However, objects and subroutines in one thread are severely limited in their ability to interact with objects and subroutines in other threads, which means that while there is a SerialPort_Datareceived event, you are very limited in what you can do in it. Even if you write the serial data to a global variable, if you also are changing that variable from the other thread, data can easily get lost as the two interfere with each other.
>
> What I ended up doing was creating an array of Bytes. The SerialPort_Datareceived event writes bytes into the array, and updates a pointer to indicate the last byte added. Then the event would Invoke a delegate subroutine in the main thread (which basically means ask the other thread to run that subroutine, at its convenience, with no passed parameters) which would eventually run. The subroutine in the other thread observes (but never changes) the pointer and the array to see what data had come in, while using its own pointer to remember the last byte it has processed. The pointer and array might well be changing while this other subroutine was running.

Since I am *not* really returning any information to the UI, I don't think it necessarily needs to be the "UI thread" handling it.

**Edit2:** If the PLM() function is already intended to work correctly even if there are multiple instances of it running at once, and I don't particularly need to sync to the UI thread, can I just fire off each instance in a new thread using System.Threading.Thread somehow instead?

Comment: You need a reference to a Form or Control object to call BeginInvoke().  So you need another variable in your Module.  In general, you ought to at least have one from a "main" window that's always around.  Assign the module variable in its constructor.  If death and despair rings the phone then Application.OpenForms(0) can do it too.

Comment: The code doesn't actually return anything to the UI anymore, currently all it does, actually, is WriteEntry to the event log. I'd hope I can get the functionality of this without having to pass the form on somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a bit more into how the original author wrote the code, and the fact that it should (relatively) safely handle multiple calls of PLM() running at the same time, I tried replacing the whole "Delegate" feature with Threading.Thread.

The following commit seems to work: https://github.com/ocdtrekkie/HAController/commit/9d9aeecce74ab40602863c6dc878ff09c89565af

Assuming this can create more than one or two threads simultaneously, if the SerialPLM_DataReceived event gets triggered, then it should work! If anyone has any suggestions regarding that, I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want that ultra big, bigger than I have ever seen, `PLM` method to run on the UI thread but apart from that you can synchronize with the UI thread by storing the calling UI (form I suppose) in the module.

Looking at your code you could refactor like using a closure:

```
Sub Load(synchronizationTarget As ISynchronizeInvoke)
    SerialPLM = New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort
    AddHandler SerialPLM.DataReceived, Sub(s, e) DataReceived(synchronizationTarget)
End Sub


Private Sub DataReceived(synchronizationTarget As ISynchronizeInvoke)
    ' omitted

    ' invoke delegate 
    Dim handler As New mySerialDelegate(AddressOf PLM)
    synchronizationTarget.BeginInvoke(handler, Nothing)
End Sub

' and use in your form like:
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    modInsteon.Load(Me)
End Sub
```

Comment: The PLM method isn't originally my code. I've actually shortened it a lot already. Work in progress! I am not sure if I need a tie to the UI thread specifically or not, that method is no longer returning any data to the UI. Eventually, I want to factor the UI out of the equation entirely,and rebuild this as a service or console application.

Answer (score 0):

Of course `Me.BeginInvoke` can't be used in a module.  `Me` can't be used in a module.  Whenever you use `Me` you're referring to the current instance of the current type.  Modules have no instances so `Me` makes no sense.

If you use `Me.BeginInvoke` in a form then you are calling the `BeginInvoke` method of the current instance.  Outside of a form, you would call it like any other method, qualifying it with a reference to the form you want to call it on.

Keep in mind that default form instances are thread-specific, so if you're using the default instance in your module then you can't call BeginInvoke because it will be on the wrong instance.

Really, the solution here is to not use a module at all but rather to use a class and the `SynchronizationContext` class within it.  Your form can create an instance of that class on the UI thread and it then gets the current `SynchronizationContext`, which can later be used to marshal a method call back tot he UI thread.

Comment: I'm aware Me can't be used in a module, the error message in VS is pretty clear. ;) I need to know how to replicate the existing functionality of this code, which doesn't actually return anything to the UI thread anymore.

Comment: "I need to know how to replicate the existing functionality of this code ...".  And I told you how to do that.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty significant rework that doesn't seem to understand the goal of this at all. I don't want the code running on the form. I edited the original question to add some notes from the original author that maybe explains what the code is trying to do better than me.

Comment: "That sounds like a pretty significant rework ...".  It's not.